# Trying to install Quandl on Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ipython, quandl

I recently changed my OS from Windows 10 to Linux, and I'm trying to install `quandl` packages using the `pip install` method. I did some googling and found the following command:

```
$ pip install quandl
```

but it wasn't successfully installed.

Comment: What error message did you get? You may also wish to consider [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is due to the lack of pip in your new linux computer.

Follow this instruction to install pip first,
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

If you have pip and installed quandl, but you can't access it in python. 
It maybe due to the path problem and I think you have to edit it.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install quandl
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

`pip3 install --user Quandl`   (for python3)

`pip install --user Quandl` (for Python2)

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: it's self explanatory

Comment: Some people who are new to linux, might not know the `apt-get` command